# Converting data frame into str in python

Tags: python

From the dataframe under 'zipcode', I would love to change the last 2 digits from the column below into `00` using python:

```
850xx
931xx
933xx
113xx
440xx
186xx
327xx
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data['zipcode'].astype(str)` convert the zipcode column to `string`.

`zipc[:3]` takes the 3 first caracters of zipc.

Something like this ?

```
In[90]: data['zipcode'] = 85055

In[91]: data['zipcode'] = [zipc[:3] + '00' for zipc in data['zipcode'].astype(str).values]

In[92]: data['zipcode']

Out[92]: 
Index
1     85000
2     85000
3     85000
4     85000
5     85000
6     85000
7     85000
8     85000
9     85000
10    85000
Name: zipcode, dtype: object
```

Comment: @JaydenYuen: I added some explanations in the post. If needed, ask a precise question on a part of the code.

Comment: I dont know what does zipc does.
also when I was trying to sort the zipcode into different dataframe.
zero = []
for i in data.zip_code:
    if i < 9999:
        zero.append(i)
print zero

it only prints []

Comment: @JaydenYuen: zipc is in the for statement which loops on the array which is defined by the data.zipcode.values. Have a look on https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html